# Implementing a iterator based shell sort

Tags: c++, iterator, shellsort

My shell sort looks like this:

```
template<class T>
void shellSort(T *begin, T *end) {
    int shell = 1;

    while (shell < (begin - end) / 3) shell = shell * 3 + 1;
    while (shell > 0) {
        for (auto index = shell; index < end; index++) {
            for (auto insertion = index; insertion >= shell && *(insertion - shell) > *(insertion); insertion -= shell) {
                swap(*(insertion - shell), *(insertion));
            }
        }

        shell = shell / 3;
    }
}
```

Pretty run of the mill. The problem I'm running into is on this line:

```
for (auto index = shell; index < end; index++)
```

Since `shell` is an `int` but `end` is an `int *` it doesn't know how to do the comparison. How do I go about resolving this?

Comment: Are you following the algorithms class on coursera by any chance?

Comment: Nah, teaching myself CS. Good to know that exists, though. Thanks!

Comment: You might wanna check the paren-balance in your posted code. You're missing one (or have an extra one, either way).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use "iterators" for addressing items, and use integers for relative offsets only:

```
for (auto index = begin + shell; index < end; ++index) ...
```

By the way, you probably want `shell < (end - begin)/3`, not `(begin - end)`.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming these are random access iterators, since the performance will be pretty bad otherwise.

You can use `std::distance` to get the difference between two iterators. You can also use `std::advance` to add an integer to an iterator.

Comment: +1 and/or `std::next` to get an offset iterator while keeping the original.